# Create Artificial Integelent Robot Ability to communicate with Computer : Which language i should use

Tags: microcontroller, artificial-intelligence, robotc

I know some languages like PHP, C/C++ and Java but I'm not expert in these languages. I want to create an Artificial Intelligent Robot that can do these Task;

1. able to communicate with Computer (USB, Bluetooth or other)
2. able to perform some specific task
3. present a  Visual interface (finding path, speed and others)
4. Access its Micro Controller device and attached devices
5. and so on..  (editor note: solve world hunger?)

Can any one please suggest which programming language will be good for programing this type of robot. I have heard about C/C++ and Assembler and ROBOTC and LABVIEW but I am unable to decided which language to use for my project.

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Before creating an AI robot, how about creating an AI program? Lot of people started 25+ years ago. All failed.

Comment: when i decide language after that i will start working on AI program thanks for your Comment

Comment: Language is not the issue... What matters more is what software has already been made for this purpose that you can easily access.  That's what will ultimately determine which language you use.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little bit like "I want to talk to people, which language should I learn?".

The answer is: Almost any. C, C++, Java, Python and many many more will all enable you to do the things you mentioned.

That being said, it depends on what are your more detailed requirements. Microcontrollers are often programmed in C, or assembly (and sometimes different languages). C++ offers high performance, but the development is a little bit more complex. Python is easy to learn and use, but programs written in it can be a little slow. Lisp is (or was?) sometimes used for AI ...

If you are learning your first programming language, I would recommend Python, or getting an [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and using Processing. Good luck :-)

Comment: thanks for answering me, what if i say to make a Iron man suit :) or something similar not same then which langauge should i use i m easy to work with C and C++ both langauges i know and can make programs easily

Comment: I'd guess C for various microcontrollers that read sensors and control motors. Then basically anything (C++, Python or Java ???) for the HUD and Jarvis. ... and get ready for a lot of failures and retrying when doing something this complex :-)

Comment: just one more Question is C deals with Biotech ? like something send signle from Mind and sensor read that signal and do specific task Looking for answer and i m ready to failure

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on the task, your robot should perform. Communication via USB or Bluetooth works equally well in all languages. Moreover, I doubt you'll need Assembler for your task. My general advice would be to use Python if your robot platform supports that or, for computation heavy tasks, C/C++. By the way, I think those languages are also most widespread in the robotics industry.

Comment: is C language deals with Bio Tech sensors like can catch signals from Mind and and C language deals with that signals do some specific task thanks

Comment: @Rahulkumar Was that a question? I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You can use any sensor from C, as well as from most other languages.

Comment: sorry , i was asking about how c langauge deals with Bio Technology and is C langauge able to perform high level work ?
anyways, i m highly greatefull to you taking time to respond my questions i m going with C and Prolog languages :)